# Wrap Container ID around DataFormWebPart in SharePoint 2010

Tags: css, sharepoint-2010, jquery-isotope, dataformwebpart

I am working on SharePoint 2010, and i am creating custom display using DataForm.Webpart. I am trying to implement the Isotope jquery Plugin and up to a point things are working ok.

But more to my question, how can I set a div/css ID to wrap around a webpart? Anywhere I try to place the container breaks the webpart.

Comment: Please share some of the code that "breaks the webpart"

Comment: Basically it breaks when I try to add a <div id="container"> anywhere in the XSL tag.
E.G.:
<xsl:stylesheet>....</xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl>.....</xsl>
I tried both in and out of both tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by coping the **entire webpart source code** (in SharePoint Designer), and with **Advanced Editing** enabled, I pasted the code just before the end of the page. This however caused the webpart to not be editable from a web browser since the code was added in the protected/safe area of the page.

```
    ....
  </table>
    <div id="container">
      <WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart ...... >
      ....
      </WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```